# Buttons wont resize correctly when using a GridBagLayout

Tags: java, jbutton, gridbaglayout

I am trying to use Java's GridBagLayout to create a form that contains 6 buttons.

The layout is supposed to look kind of like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Speln.jpg

So its supposed to be two large buttons on top with 4 smaller ones underneath but all equal sizes. 
As you can see from the image above they are not all the same size. 
How would i fix this?

This is the code i have to lay it out:

```
public void InitialiseComponents() {
    btnSouthWestBlockManagement = new JButton();
    btnDevonBlockManagement = new JButton();
    btnAccounts = new JButton();
    btnContacts = new JButton();
    btnIssuesRegister = new JButton();
    btnMaintainance = new JButton();

    btnDevonBlockManagement.setText("Devon Block Management");
    btnSouthWestBlockManagement.setText("South West Block Management");
    btnAccounts.setText("Accounts");
    btnContacts.setText("Contacts");
    btnIssuesRegister.setText("Issues Register");
    btnMaintainance.setText("Maintainance");

    this.add(btnDevonBlockManagement, sizeComponent(0, 0, 2, 1, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, 0.5, 0.5));
    this.add(btnSouthWestBlockManagement, sizeComponent(2, 0, 2, 1, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, 0.5, 0.5));
    this.add(btnAccounts, sizeComponent(0, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, 0.25, 0.5));
    this.add(btnContacts, sizeComponent(1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, 0.25, 0.5));
    this.add(btnIssuesRegister, sizeComponent(2, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, 0.25, 0.5));
    this.add(btnMaintainance, sizeComponent(3, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, 0.25, 0.5));

}

protected GridBagConstraints sizeComponent(int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight, int fill, int anchor, double weightx, double weighty) {
    GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;
    gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = gridx;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = gridy;
    gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = gridwidth;
    gridBagConstraints.gridheight = gridheight;
    gridBagConstraints.fill = fill;
    gridBagConstraints.anchor = anchor;
    gridBagConstraints.weightx = weightx;
    gridBagConstraints.weighty = weighty;
    return gridBagConstraints;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by adding struts in the top column to keep all the components the same size. the code i used was

```
    this.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(100), sizeComponent(0, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, 0, 0));
    this.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(100), sizeComponent(1, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, 0, 0));
    this.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(100), sizeComponent(2, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, 0, 0));
    this.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(100), sizeComponent(3, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, 0, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to have buttons (or components of any sort) that are equal size in rows and/or columns is to create a grid.  Make 1-row grids for the buttons, and perhaps a 3-row grid for the panels that hold the buttons.  That may not be what you want, I cannot tell from your description, but a grid is what to use for same-size components, and nesting grids (or any layout) is standard for good Swing layouts.